# display same set of questions for every checked checkboxes. (PHP and JS/Jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have set of checkboxes, and when they get checked I have to display questions. These question will always be the same. this is done in PHP

Example

Checkbox1
Checkbox1
Checkbox1
Checkbox1

if checkbox 1 and 3 are selected  and should display

Checkbox1 : date from and date to and start time and end time 
Checkbox 3: date from and date to and start time and end time

if checkbox 4 get checked another box for checkbox4 should appear with same questions and it should display.

Checkbox 1: date from and date to and start time and end time 
Checkbox 3: date from and date to and start time and end time 
Checkbox 4: date from and date to and start time and end time

if checkbox 3 gets unchecked, it should take away checkbox3 questions and it shoud display only checkbox 1 and 4 questions
Checkbox 1: date from and date to and start time and end time 
Checkbox 4: date from and date to and start time and end time

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, it may helps you...

**HTML**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="button" id="btnadd" name="btnadd" value="Add Question"/>
  <input type="button" id="btnreset" name="btnreset" value="Reset"/>
  <div id="quecheckbox">
  </div>
  <div id="quelist">
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function show_ques() {
        var i = $(this).attr('id').substr(-1);
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //get total count of question list 
            var nQue = $("#quelist").find("div[class^=que]").length;
            var isSet = false; //boolean to check if que is appended or not. 
            if (nQue > 0) {
                var nq = 0;
                $("#quelist").find("div[class^=que]:last").attr('class').substr(-1);
                $("#quelist").find("div[class^=que]").each(function() {
                    nq = $(this).attr('class').substr(-1);

                    if (nq > i && !isSet) {
                        $("#quelist .que" + nq).before("<div class='que" + i + "'>Question " + i + " is....?</div>");
                        isSet = true;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (!isSet) {
                $("#quelist").append("<div class='que" + i + "'>Question " + i + " is....?</div>");
            }
        } else {
            $("#quelist").find("div.que" + i).remove();
        }
 }
$(function() {
        $("#btnadd").click(function() {
            var i = $("#quecheckbox").find("input[type=checkbox]").length;
            if (i <= 0) i = 1;
            else i += 1;
            $("#quecheckbox").append("<div><input type='checkbox' id='que" + i + "' name='que" + i + "'/><label for='que" + i + "'>Question " + i + "</div>");

            $("#que" + i).bind('change', show_ques);

        });
        $("#btnreset").click(function() {
            $("#quecheckbox").html("");
            $("#quelist").html("");
        });
 });
```

I have done bin for above issue on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa8

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. For future reference, you should probably try something yourself and then ask questions on why it may not be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickcaballero/U7JGW/